# I need to know the simplest way to draw a shape in gtk with cairo

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo

Can someone tell me the SIMPLEST way to draw like a rectangle in a window in `gtk`? Please? Simple. Here is a challenge. Write a file to draw ANY `cairo` shape in a few lines of code possible. I found working drawing code online, but it is super complicated and not all of it is necessary. Can someone write me the code to draw any `cairo` shape in a few lines of code possible so I can use it as reference for my game?

Here is some working code, but is much to complicated. I don't need to draw rectangles were the mouse clicks, just draw one rectangle from four numbers. Someone, please reduce this to what is ABSOLUTELY necessary to draw one rectangle. Preferably I wanna draw a rectangle without any other functions other than the main function (Once the main function returns zero, everything ends)

The code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* Surface to store current scribbles */
static cairo_surface_t *surface = NULL;

static void
clear_surface (void)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  cr = cairo_create (surface);

  cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 1, 1, 1);
  cairo_paint (cr);

  cairo_destroy (cr);
}

/* Create a new surface of the appropriate size to store our scribbles */
static gboolean
configure_event_cb (GtkWidget         *widget,
                    GdkEventConfigure *event,
                    gpointer           data)
{
  if (surface)
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

  surface = gdk_window_create_similar_surface (gtk_widget_get_window (widget),
                                               CAIRO_CONTENT_COLOR,
                                               gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (widget),
                                               gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (widget));

  /* Initialize the surface to white */
  clear_surface ();

  /* We've handled the configure event, no need for further processing. */
  return TRUE;
}

/* Redraw the screen from the surface. Note that the ::draw
 * signal receives a ready-to-be-used cairo_t that is already
 * clipped to only draw the exposed areas of the widget
 */
static gboolean
draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget,
         cairo_t   *cr,
         gpointer   data)
{
  cairo_set_source_surface (cr, surface, 0, 0);
  cairo_paint (cr);

  return FALSE;
}

/* Draw a rectangle on the surface at the given position */
static void
draw_brush (GtkWidget *widget,
            gdouble    x,
            gdouble    y)
{
  cairo_t *cr;

  /* Paint to the surface, where we store our state */
  cr = cairo_create (surface);

  cairo_rectangle (cr, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
  cairo_fill (cr);

  cairo_destroy (cr);

  /* Now invalidate the affected region of the drawing area. */
  gtk_widget_queue_draw_area (widget, x - 3, y - 3, 6, 6);
}

/* Handle button press events by either drawing a rectangle
 * or clearing the surface, depending on which button was pressed.
 * The ::button-press signal handler receives a GdkEventButton
 * struct which contains this information.
 */
static gboolean
button_press_event_cb (GtkWidget      *widget,
                       GdkEventButton *event,
                       gpointer        data)
{
  /* paranoia check, in case we haven't gotten a configure event */
  if (surface == NULL)
    return FALSE;

  if (event->button == GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY)
    {
      draw_brush (widget, event->x, event->y);
    }
  else if (event->button == GDK_BUTTON_SECONDARY)
    {
      clear_surface ();
      gtk_widget_queue_draw (widget);
    }

  /* We've handled the event, stop processing */
  return TRUE;
}

/* Handle motion events by continuing to draw if button 1 is
 * still held down. The ::motion-notify signal handler receives
 * a GdkEventMotion struct which contains this information.
 */
static gboolean
motion_notify_event_cb (GtkWidget      *widget,
                        GdkEventMotion *event,
                        gpointer        data)
{
  /* paranoia check, in case we haven't gotten a configure event */
  if (surface == NULL)
    return FALSE;

  if (event->state & GDK_BUTTON1_MASK)
    draw_brush (widget, event->x, event->y);

  /* We've handled it, stop processing */
  return TRUE;
}

static void
close_window (void)
{
  if (surface)
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *frame;
  GtkWidget *drawing_area;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Drawing Area");

  g_signal_connect (window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (close_window), NULL);

  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 8);

  frame = gtk_frame_new (NULL);
  gtk_frame_set_shadow_type (GTK_FRAME (frame), GTK_SHADOW_IN);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), frame);

  drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  /* set a minimum size */
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (drawing_area, 100, 100);

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frame), drawing_area);

  /* Signals used to handle the backing surface */
  g_signal_connect (drawing_area, "draw",
                    G_CALLBACK (draw_cb), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (drawing_area,"configure-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (configure_event_cb), NULL);

  /* Event signals */
  g_signal_connect (drawing_area, "motion-notify-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (motion_notify_event_cb), NULL);
  g_signal_connect (drawing_area, "button-press-event",
                    G_CALLBACK (button_press_event_cb), NULL);

  /* Ask to receive events the drawing area doesn't normally
   * subscribe to. In particular, we need to ask for the
   * button press and motion notify events that want to handle.
   */
  gtk_widget_set_events (drawing_area, gtk_widget_get_events (drawing_area)
                                     | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK
                                     | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `static` all over the place

Comment: @I don't know. I got this code from an html website and I could not understand how it works when drawing the shaps

Comment: @16squared Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you talk a bit about what you tried yourself to reduce the code to its simplest form? Generally, this isn't a website where people write your code for you, so I'd advise you to try and simplify the code yourself, and ask for help if you need it about something specific in the code you posted that you need help understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone tell me the SIMPLEST way to draw like a rectangle in a
>   window in gtk?

Yes, but you will just get a default Gtk window with a `cairo_rectangle` filling the default 200x200 window with a 10-pixel border around the rectangle. There isn't much to drawing a rectangle, (you don't even have to fill it with a separate color - though that makes it indistinguishable from the normal window background).

Simply create the gtk window and add the cairo drawing area using the gtk window as a container (you won't be able to add anything else to the window unless you use a layout container like vbox, etc..)

About the minimal would be:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void draw_rect (cairo_t *cr)
{
    cairo_rectangle (cr, 10, 10, 180, 180);     /* set rectangle */
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6);   /* set fill color */
    cairo_fill (cr);                            /* fill rectangle */
}

static gboolean on_draw_event (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr,
                                gpointer user_data)
{
    draw_rect (cr);     /* draw rectangle in window */

    return FALSE;
    (void)user_data, (void)widget;  /* suppress -Wunused warning */
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;          /* gtk windows */
    GtkWidget *darea;           /* cairo drawing area */

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);    /* required with every gtk app */

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);  /* create window */
    darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();                 /* create cairo area */
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);   /* add to window */

    /* connect callbacks to draw rectangle and close window/quit app */
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(darea), "draw",
                        G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all (window);   /* show all windows */

    gtk_main();     /* pass control to gtk event-loop */
}
```

(**note:** you can remove the `(void)user_data, (void)widget;` line which just suppresses an unused parameter warning)

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -O3 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cairo_rectangle_min
```

[image]